# Do I need to include GENERATED ALWAYS AS in my trigger if it is not assigned a value in the INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to do a PLSQL trigger that will initialize VenteID, CoutTotalOption, TauxEscompteSaisonnier, IndicateurFidelite, TauxEscompteFidelite, TaxeProvCourante, TaxeFedCourante when the INSERT statement only includes NoSerieVehicule,ClientID,ModeFinCd, EmplID, DateVente, PrixVenteVehicule. [image: Here's an image of said table.]

Definition of the table :

```
CREATE TABLE AU_Ventes (
VenteID                 NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
NoSerieVehicule         CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
ClientID                NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
ModeFinCd               CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
EmplID                  NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
TauxEscompteSaisonnier  NUMBER(5,4),
DateVente               DATE 
                        DEFAULT SYSDATE
                        NOT NULL,
DateFinGarantie         AS (ADD_MONTHS(DateVente,60)),
PrixSuggere             NUMBER(8,2),
PrixVenteVehicule       NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
EscompteSaisonnier      NUMBER(8,2),
IndicateurFidelite      CHAR(1),
TauxEscompteFidelite    NUMBER(5,4),
CoutVehiculeEscompte    NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier),
CoutTotalOption         NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
TotalVenteTaxable       NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (PrixVenteVehicule - (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier) + CoutTotalOption ),
TaxeFedCourante         NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((PrixVenteVehicule - (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier) + CoutTotalOption ) * 0.05), 
TaxeProvCourante        NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((PrixVenteVehicule - (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier) + CoutTotalOption ) * 1.05 ) * 0.095),
TotalTaxes              NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((PrixVenteVehicule - (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier) + CoutTotalOption )*(0.05+(1.05*0.095))),
GrandTotalVente         NUMBER(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((PrixVenteVehicule - (PrixVenteVehicule * (TauxEscompteFidelite + TauxEscompteSaisonnier) + EscompteSaisonnier) + CoutTotalOption )*(1+0.05+(1.05*0.095))),
CONSTRAINT PK_VenteID PRIMARY KEY (VenteID),
CONSTRAINT FK_NoSerieVehicule FOREIGN KEY (NoSerieVehicule) REFERENCES AU_Vehicules (NoSerieVehicule),
CONSTRAINT FK_ClientID FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES AU_Clients (ClientID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ModeFinCd FOREIGN KEY (ModeFinCd) REFERENCES AU_ModesFinancements (ModeFinCd),
CONSTRAINT CK_PrixVenteVehicule   CHECK (PrixVenteVehicule >= 0),
CONSTRAINT CK_EscompteSaisonnier  CHECK (EscompteSaisonnier >= 0),
CONSTRAINT CK_CoutTotalOption     CHECK (CoutTotalOption >= 0));
```

Here's my PLSQL code so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_06InsVente
BEFORE INSERT ON AU_Ventes
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (:new.VenteID IS NULL) --IS THIS NEEDED?
DECLARE

v_VenteID = AU_Ventes.VenteID%TYPE;
v_TauxEscompteSaisonnier = AU_Ventes.TauxEscompteSaisonnier%TYPE;
v_IndicateurFidelite = AU_Ventes.IndicateurFidelite%TYPE;
v_TauxEscompteFidelite = AU_Ventes.TauxEscompteFidelite%TYPE;
v_TaxeFedCourante = AU_Ventes.TaxeFedCourante%TYPE;
v_TaxeProvCourante = AU_Ventes.TaxeProvCourante%TYPE;
v_CoutTotalOption = AU_Ventes.CoutTotalOption%TYPE;

BEGIN

--VenteId
SELECT SEQ_VenteId.NEXTVAL INTO v_VenteID FROM DUAL;

:new.VenteID := v_VenteID;

--TauxEscompteSaisonnier
SELECT AU_Modeles.TauxEscompteSaisonnier INTO v_TauxEscompteSaisonnier
FROM AU_Vehicules INNER JOIN AU_Modeles
ON (AU_Vehicules.ModeCd = au_modeles.modecd)
WHERE ((AU_Vehicules.NoSerieVehicule = :new.NoSerieVehicule) AND 
(datefinescomptesaisonnier >= sysdate))

:new.TauxEscompteSaisonnier := v_TauxEscompteSaisonnier;

--IndicateurFidelite
SELECT AU_Clients.IndicateurFidelite INTO v_IndicateurFidelite
FROM AU_Clients 
WHERE (AU_Clients.ClientID = :new.ClientID)

:new.IndicateurFidelite := v_IndicateurFidelite;

--TauxEscompteFidelite
SELECT AU_Modeles.TauxEscompteFidelite INTO v_TauxEscompteFidelite
 FROM AU_Modeles INNER JOIN AU_Vehicules
 ON AU_Modeles.ModeCd = AU_Vehicules.ModeCd
 WHERE ((AU_Vehicules.NoSerieVehicule = :new.NoSerieVehicule) AND
 ('1' = (SELECT AU_Clients.IndicateurFidelite FROM AU_Clients 
 WHERE AU_Clients.ClientID = :new.ClientID)))

:new.v_TauxEscompteFidelite := v_TauxEscompteFidelite;

--v_TaxeFedCourante what do I do with this since it is "GENERATED ALWAYS AS"
--v_TaxeProvCourante what do I do with this since it is "GENERATED ALWAYS AS"
--v_CoutTotalOption not sure about this either HARDCODED in inserts from teacher


EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
enregistrer_erreur();
RAISE;
END;
/
```

Basically what I do not understand is if I will need to init the colums value in PLSQL and if yes how do I do that? Since it is a virtual column?

Sorry if the variables names are in French hopefully you will still be able to understand my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that I understand the question you're asking.

You cannot assign values to a virtual column in a table.  Oracle automatically generates the values.  You can ignore those columns in your trigger.

I'm hoping that this is a homework problem since you have a comment referencing a "teacher".  If not, your data model looks quite suspect-- it appears that your table is heavily denormalized since you're copying data from a number of different tables.  That is virtually never a good idea because it is very, very difficult to keep all the data synchronized.